# Arrangements (?) from permutations of rows in a triangle, is there a simpler way to program this?

Tags: code-review, combinatorics

I am generally confused about integer valued polynomials, and how to count them. Trying to learn the subject I started by listing permutations of the rows in a lower triangular table:

$$\displaystyle T = \left(\begin{matrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots \\ 1&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&1&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&1&1&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{matrix}\right)$$

with the following Mathematica program:

```
Table[
 a = Table[1, {n, 1, k}];
 nn = Length[a];
 b = Flatten[
   Table[Permutations[
     Table[Table[If[n >= k, a[[n - k + 1]], 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 0, 
        nn}][[i]]], {i, 1, nn + 1}], 1];
 ArrayPlot[b], {k, 0, 6}]
```

The last output is the following arrayplot that could be shown in matrix form too:

[image: confusion]

Is there a simpler way to program this?

Comment: I could not find the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to construct the matrix `b`:

```
m = 6;
aa = LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {m + 1, m}], -1];
bb = Join @@ Permutations /@ aa;
bb == b
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of the code review tag:

This piece of code

```
a = Table[1, {n, 1, k}];
nn = Length[a];
```

is better written as

```
nn = 6;
a = ConstantArray[1, nn];
```

because it makes the assignment of `nn` explicit. In your newer version of the code you could use `k` throughout, there is no reason to define `nn`.

You're not often going to see experienced Mathematica users use nested `Table` commands, kguler's answer shows that they are unnecessary. However if you do you should use *one* `Table` with several indices.

```
Table[{a, b}, {b, 5}, {a, 5}] == Table[Table[{a, b}, {a, 5}], {b, 5}]
(* True *)
```

So you can write your nested `Table` like this:

```
t1 = Table[
   If[n >= k, a[[n - k + 1]], 0],
   {n, 0, nn}, {k, 1, nn}
   ];
```

Also an iterator like `{n, 1, 5}` can be written more tersely as `{n, 5}` - the `1` is not needed.

Finally, whenever you find yourself doing something like `Table[f[list[[i]]], {i, 10}]` this is a clear sign that you are doing something inefficiently, probably because of your prior experience with procedural languages. This syntax is identical to the much cleaner

```
f /@ list
```

Therefore matrix `b` can be computed with

```
b = Flatten[Permutations /@ t1, 1];
```

All taken together:

```
nn = 6;
a = ConstantArray[1, nn];
t1 = Table[
   If[n >= k, a[[n - k + 1]], 0],
   {n, 0, nn}, {k, 1, nn}
   ];
b = Flatten[Permutations /@ t1, 1];
ArrayPlot[b]
```

I created the intermediate symbol `t1` which is not in your code. It's a good idea to divide things up. While in principle every Mathematica program can be a one-liner, the readability of the code will suffer. Readability is very important.

As I indicated above, experienced users gravitate towards functional solutions and so should you. Every time you find yourself writing loop like solutions using `For`, `Do` or `Table` take some time and think about if you can express the same thing with the functional operators.

Comment: I will take this into consideration, but I am originally a spreadsheet formula coder in Microsoft Excel, so it will take some time to learn functional operators.